# Jakarta EE bom: Why are SOAP dependencies added and removed?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I am migrating a server applicating from Java EE 7 to Jakarta EE 8. I noticed that the dependency `javax:jaxws-api`,
which was part of `javax:javaee-api`, is now no longer a part of `jakarta.jakartaee-bom` in version 8. However, it seems to be back in [Jakarta EE 9](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-api/blob/master/jakartaee-bom/pom.xml).

Maybe my understanding of the `jakartaee-bom` is flawed, but I thought that the bom should encapsulate **all** Jakarta EE APIs, so I am a bit puzzled that SOAP seems to have been out of scope for version 8.

Does anyone know why this removal and readdition happened? And are there any online resources that mention it - I struggled to find any piece of news on this.

Comment: The JAX-WS is a special case because it's included in the Java 8 JDK, though removed in the Java 11 JDK.   In Jakarta EE 9, there is also no JDK equivalent overlapping because now we have moved from the javax.* to the jakarta.* package namespace.    I believe the Jakarta EE 8 platform Maven artifacts basically copied the ones from Java EE 8.   Since it might be hard to find someone who can explain the history of the decision, let me ask instead:  is there something you're trying to do in particular?

Comment: I am trying to understand two things:
1) Is Jakartaee-bom really the one and only dependency that you need for Jakarta EE applications at compile time or do you have to add others?
2) What is the correct way to manage SOAP dependencies in a Jakarta EE application with webservices and is this about to change soon (deprecation etc.)?

Comment: But importing dependencyManagement via a "BOM" doesn't add any compile-time dependencies, it only specifies versions for the dependencies you define.   A simple approach that works across Java EE 7/8, Jakarta EE 8/9  is to simply declare a dependency to the aggregate platform API dependency (as in https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/the_only_one_dependency_you).   This works in EE 8 because you pick up the SOAP dependency from the JDK.  If you need to customize further that's left to you, but you don't necessarily need to.   Maybe post your pom.xml if you still have questions?